# Why is jQuery is not checking/unchecking checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

When I run the following self-contained code, the checkbox gets checked and unchecked once but thereafter it doesn't even though the messages seem to imply the toggling.

```
<html>  
<head>
<title>dummy</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="fc" type="checkbox" />
<script>
function f () {
  if (typeof $("#fc").attr("checked") !== 'undefined') {
    alert("checked, unchecking");
    $("#fc").removeAttr("checked");
  } else {
    alert("unchecked, checking");
    $("#fc").attr("checked", "checked");
  }
  setTimeout(f, 1000);
}
setTimeout(f, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tested in Firefox and it seems to work the first time, but then it's just rendered as unchecked.

Comment: correct, same for me in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 20, accepted):

need to use .prop() instead of .attr() to check and uncheck checkboxes

```
$("#fc").prop("checked", true);// true to check false to uncheck
```

Also use :checked filter to check whether a checkbox is checked

```
function f () {
    if ($("#fc").is(":checked")) {
        alert("checked, unchecking");
        $("#fc").prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        alert("unchecked, checking");
        $("#fc").prop("checked", true);
    }
    setTimeout(f, 1000);
}
setTimeout(f, 1000);
```

The above given sample can be simplified as

```
function f () {
    $("#fc").prop("checked", !$("#fc").is(":checked"));
}
setInterval(f, 1000);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NGMtM/)

Comment: @Vandesh: There's plenty wrong with it.  See, one big difference between the `checked` *attribute* and the `checked` *property*, is that the property gets/sets the current value, and the attribute gets/sets the initial value (and won't affect the state of the box afterward).

Comment: Or `$("#fc").prop("checked", function(i, v) { return !v; });`

Comment: @cHao: Then why does adding and removing the attribute check and uncheck the box the first time?

Comment: @FelixKling: Not sure.  It's rather broken that only the first iteration works, IMO.  It should either work every time or not work at all.  Its only working once makes finding issues like this more difficult.

Comment: @Vandesh: Did you happen to try doing it in an interval?  It checks the box once, unchecks it once, then nothing.  See http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fDZXR/1/